# Apply function through each row to determine sentences' structure

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I am trying to add a new column including the sentence's structure for each row of this dataset:

```
Sentence
    I ate an apple pie, yesterday. 
    I ate an orange, yesterday.
    I eat a lemon, today.
```

I have written the following in order to apply this function to each row:

```
def stru():
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

    doc = nlp(file.Sentence)
    pos = ""
    for token in doc:
        pos += token.pos_ + " "
    return
```

then `df.Struct=df.Sentence.apply(stru)`

My expected output would be something like this:

```
Sentence                                  Struct
    I ate an apple pie, yesterday.        PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE
    I ate an orange, yesterday.           PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE         
    I eat a lemon, today.                 PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE
```

Can you please tell me what it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the specific sentence to the function, and "return" the result, i.e. pos:

```
def stru(sentence):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    pos = ""
    for token in doc:
        pos += token.pos_ + " "
    return pos
```

Comment: I would try: doc = nlp(sentence)

Comment: I am going to mark it, gtomer, as soon as I can :) I am just trying to understand how to get the expected output

Comment: I made another correction. You need to return the result = pos. See above

Comment: Thanks gtomer. I have a doubt regarding sentence (argument): this is not my column, is it not? So when I apply the function to my column, which argument should I pass?

Comment: You pass one row at a time

Comment: so I should call it as follows, if I understood correctly: `df['Struct']=df.Sentence.apply(stru(sentence))`

Comment: No need. By applying the function to the specific column it works on it. Run the code I posted above in my ANSWER. It will work as is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221349/discussion-between-val-and-gtomer).